# 'TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified' when connecting to oracle instance through cx_Oracle

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cx-oracle

I have an Oracle instance on a AWS EC2 instance. When I run this in the AWS linux terminal, it is successful.

`ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:~$ sqlplus user101/pass101@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:1521/XE`

[image]

However, when I run the same arguments when connecting through cx_Oracle I get a:

`"ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified" error`

[image]

I know some common problems are with the `tnsnames.ora` file. I've placed that below.

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ip-172-xx-xx-xx)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

~
```

Comment: Are you running Python in the same place as you are running SQL*Plus?

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga I am using ssh to access the AWS server where SQL is, I am running Python locally.

Comment: So the answer is no? If you run Python from the same terminal as SQL*Plus you should get the same results. If you're running elsewhere, you'll have to ensure the configuration is set up correctly there.

Comment: Have you tried with python-oracledb? It has a thin mode that may provide better (or at least different) error messages.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the full Easy Connect syntax is being interpreted as a TNS entry.

According to [the `Connect()` documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#cx_Oracle.connect), you can use your current code if you specify that you are passing the `user` argument:

> If the user parameter is passed and the password and dsn parameters are not passed, the user parameter is assumed to be a connect string in the format user/password@dsn, the same format accepted by Oracle applications such as SQL*Plus.

So this should work:

```
connection = cx_oracle.Connect(user="user101/pass101@ip-172-xx-xx-xx:1521/XE")
```

According to [the Oracle connection handling documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html), you could also split that out:

```
connection = cx_oracle.Connect(
                 user="user101",
                 password="pass101",
                 dsn="ip-172-xx-xx-xx:1521/XE",
                 encoding="UTF-8"
             )
```

Or if you want to use `tnsnames.ora` then just give that alias as the DSN value:

```
connection = cx_oracle.Connect(
                 user="user101",
                 password="pass101",
                 dsn="XE",
                 encoding="UTF-8"
             )
```

Comment: I just tried all 3 of those and unfortunately got the same error for all 3.

Comment: So what error are you getting?